# JavaScript Print Time with AM/PM Displayed?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to print out a section of a web page and I need it to display the time input by the user to be displayed in the format of 4:30 PM but it leaves off the PM.  Using the following code, it will display the time input in the the input box with the type TIME, except for the A or P.  When I use the window.print() function, it displays the A or P, but also displays the entire page, which is not what we are wanting.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var divToPrint=document.getElementById('tablePrint');
newWin= window.open("");
newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
newWin.print();
newWin.close();   
}
</script>
```

This is a snippet of the html code:

```
<tr>
<th> Day  </th>
<th> In   </th> 
<th> Out  </th>
<th> In   </th> 
<th> Out  </th>
<th> Total</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><lable>Fri </lable></td>
<td><input style="width:80px" type="time" name="TPL_a_a_i_fri" size=6 maxlength=6 value="{A_A_I_FRI}"></td>
<td><input style="width:80px" type="time" name="TPL_a_a_o_fri" size=6 maxlength=6 value="{A_A_O_FRI}"></td>
<td><input style="width:80px" type="time" name="TPL_a_p_i_fri" size=6 maxlength=6 value="{A_P_I_FRI}"></td>
<td><input style="width:80px" type="time" name="TPL_a_p_o_fri" size=6 maxlength=6 value="{A_P_O_FRI}"></td>
<td><input style="width:50px" type="text" name="TPL_a_tot_fri" size=6 maxlength=6 value="{A_TOT_FRI}"></td>
</tr>
```

The name and value are dealt with in a php file that is used to calculate time worked.

Comment: how about some HTML? we have no context to go off

Comment: Or, even better, create a working code snippet.

Comment: Also, the user input is done in the format of hh:mm t.  The user inputs it this way and it will open a print form in the format of hh:mm with no t.  If that helps any.  I have been stumped by this for a few weeks now and can not find anything or anyone who has had a similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

try to use this format

```
 document.write(new Date().toString("hh:mm tt"));
```

Comment: would this work if it had two table that consisted of Monday through Friday in each table?  Forgive me, but I am new to JavaScript.  Or would I have to iterate through it in a loop to apply to each input?

Comment: When was formatted output added to [*Date.prototype.toString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.2)?